# What is that tower they always show in Grey's anatomy?

Tags: greys-anatomy

In every episode of Grey's anatomy, they show a tower. What is that?
Is it some landmark in Seattle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the Space Needle, which is seen in many episodes, it is a well-known landmark in Seattle, Washington. As you mentioned, the show is set in Seattle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: After 4 years, I'm working at Amazon and I have a view of Space Needle from my work place.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Harborview Medical Center in Seattle that has a central tower structure as opposed to the Space Needle? Here's a photo.

[image]

This is the setting for the series.